# PIL draw text without gray outline

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to generate text using PIL for a black and white image only, but the text has this gray outline that I'm trying to get rid off.

```
image = np.zeros((600, 600), dtype=np.uint8)
image[:] = 255
img = Image.fromarray(image, 'L')
fnt = ImageFont.truetype('Arial.ttf', 50)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((50,100), 'test , test', font=fnt)
```

[image]

What do I need to do to get the text to appear only in black? No gray area around it?

Comment: I assume, you complain about the **antialiasing**, to make the font appearing smoother. Since anatialiasing was a key achievement by TTF you should probably look for another font type, but [this](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getmask) may also help.

Comment: Any example for how to use it?

Comment: There may be better methods, or you may be able to disable antialiasing, but as a temporary solution, you could **threshold** to force every shade of grey to black or white. A low threshold will make your letters thinner, a high threshold will make them fatter - maybe start at 50% and see :-)

Comment: Well, that's only if you make the image bigger then it will look like pixels but if you don't make it big it looks perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [ImageFont.getmask](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getmask) and [ImageFont.getsize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getsize) methods I was able to create a `PIL.Image` object that masks text with hard edges.

[image]

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont

fnt = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 50)
text = 'test, test'
img = Image.new('1', fnt.getsize(text))
mask = [x for x in fnt.getmask(text, mode='1')]
img.putdata(mask)
```

This `PIL.Image` object (`img`) can be used to add the text to your image wherever you please, if you need more info on this I can build an example for you. Keep in mind that `img.mode` is `'1'`, which means black and white. Every pixel (returned by `img.getpixel`) is either 0 or 255.